# Datetimepicker plus DJANGO not loading correctly

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have been going crazy in order to understand what's going on but I can't seem to figure out what is the problem. It only happens in production, not in dev server. Here is my config:

Settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

base.html (the layout im extending)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

{% load static %}

{% load bootstrap4 %}

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>WHARFY</title>
  {% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
  {% bootstrap_css %}

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
  <link href='{% static "vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"%}' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <link href='{% static "css/sb-admin-2.min.css" %}' rel="stylesheet">
```

model_update.html (Im using UpdateView)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% block content %}

{{ form.media }}

<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  {% bootstrap_form form %}
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

While in dev I do not have any problems, in production i get this error from the console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
datepicker-widget.css:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
datepicker-widget.css:1
```

The datetime picker doesn't show up(ONLY IN PRODUCTION)

I properly installed using datetimepicker plus and also bootstrap and also successfully run the following command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

I'm new to django, I found similar questions but couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: There is probably something wrong with your static files. Check that the file `datepicker-widget.css` is in the correct URL from client side.
What happens if you go to URL `http://yourwebsite/whatever/css/datepicker-widget.css`?

Comment: That's the strange thing. Everything seems to be correctly collected by django. I can see the static directory in the same directory of the project. And of course it is loading everything else (im using a theme). The theme is loaded so Django does have access to the files.

Comment: If I go to the url using the browser it's a 404 (nginx)